# Improving species richness map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

[image]

I asked for help in [Creating species distribution map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/138849) about creating a species richness map out of X/Y coordinates and an information how many species there are in each coordinate. I finally got it done. But the result is not very nice (see picture 1). I used graduated colors and then squares of size 4, to not get single points everywhere, but kind of closed layers.

1. Do you have any idea how to improve this?
2. How can I get my map to a nicer shape as we are used to, like in picture 2?

[image]

---

This is the result so far.

Any ideas how to improve it?

Or do you think the first map without any projection was better?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide further details about the creation of the map? As I understand, you present the points with symbology aimed to create a surface-like presentation. Have you considered using an interpolation to predict a biodiversity surface from your points? it might as well help you with the aesthtics of your output.

Comment: Looks like a Mercator projection (pic1) you need to reproject the data in Robinson Projection (pic2) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Robinson/003r0000003z000000/

Comment: Hello dof1985. That is exactly what I did. Sorry for not being precise enough. I got coordinates with a value of how many species occur there (At XY 11 species, at XYZ 15 species).
I dont want to do too much interpolation of any kind, because this map right now is already an interpolation. The occurences are derived from habitat features, not from actual sightings. You understand what I mean? But if it allows for improving the aethetics without actually changing the result, that would be interesting. That said, I was more looking for tips how to design what I have.
I really appreciate you help

Comment: @ Mapperz: I did not use any projection at all. It is just WGS1984. But can I change that to the Robinson Projection you mentioned, without changing the actual result? I dont want that, because the result is fine - I was just hoping to be able to "pimp" it a little bit for the publication. I am thankful for any hint. Cheers!

Comment: @Sara Yes, you can reproject in the Robinson projection without changing the actual result. You just need to change the coordinate system of your dataframe.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer you got to your previous question? http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/138875/187

Comment: Thanks to Mapperz and radouxju. I will upload how it looks now. What do you guys with more experience think looks better? Any other ideas how to improve it? I think what looks a little rough are the edges (because it is point data with squares). Any idea how to make them a little smoother, so it appears like even surfaces of different colors?



@underdark: Nothing was really wrong, but I have a different data set now with 3 columns: Lon, Lat and no. of species. And I work with ArcMap and not QGis and did not find out how to create heat maps there.

Comment: what you are telling sound more as a ecological modelling, rather than interpolation. As @underdark was saying - heatmap is a good tool for you to show the density of species in space; in Arcgis the tools are the point or kernel [density](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000000v000000.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The aesthetics might look better if you used colors that are more similar to one another, so you wouldn't get such an affront to your eyes. If you look inside national geographic, they often have basemap features in dark grays and blacks, with dividing lines in white, with a single color representing the variable they are showing. Usually a muted red. Using a more simple 1-color ramp might produce more nice-looking results!

Also, I'm not too sure how your data is coded, but if you have more continuous data than ~10 levels, you may want to just add more levels in between so the colors change more gradually than what you're showing here.

Also a legend would be helpful to show what the colors mean!